# two different table join mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 table which one:

**Albums:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `albums` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `singer` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `releaseDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `categoryId` (`categoryId`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

**Music:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `musics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `singer` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `genre` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `albumId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `releaseDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `categoryId` (`categoryId`),
  KEY `albumId` (`albumId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;
```

I want join that's table and ordered by releaseDate. It's possible?
Sorry for my english.

**RESULT:**
Now I get some result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
| albums_name                                   | musics_name             | releaseDate |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
| The Artificial Theory For The Dramatic Beauty | K                       | NULL        |
| The Artificial Theory For The Dramatic Beauty | Fiction In Hope         | NULL        |
| The Artificial Theory For The Dramatic Beauty | Chemicarium             | NULL        |
| The Artificial Theory For The Dramatic Beauty | Voice                   | NULL        |
| The Artificial Theory For The Dramatic Beauty | Blue                    | NULL        |
| The Artificial Theory For The Dramatic Beauty | Mirror                  | NULL        |
| The Artificial Theory For The Dramatic Beauty | If You Want To Wake Up? | NULL        |
| The Artificial Theory For The Dramatic Beauty | Interlude               | NULL        |
| NULL                                          | Everything At Once      | 2010-11-11  |
| NULL                                          | Blue Freightliner       | 2011-11-11  |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

I want:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
| albums_name                                   | musics_name             | releaseDate |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
| The Artificial Theory For The Dramatic Beauty | NULL                    | 2009-11-11  |
| NULL                                          | Everything At Once      | 2010-11-11  |
| NULL                                          | Blue Freightliner       | 2011-11-11  |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Show some data and the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two very distinct parts that your output appears to consist of:

- albums and their release dates;
- album-less tracks and their release dates.

Each part coming from a different table, this strikes me as a classic example of a *union*, not a join, of two sets:

```
SELECT
  name AS albums_name,
  NULL AS musics_name,
  releaseDate
FROM albums

UNION ALL

SELECT
  NULL AS albums_name,
  name AS musics_name,
  releaseDate
FROM musics
WHERE
  album_id IS NULL

ORDER BY
  releaseDate ASC
;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do some studying / playing with `JOIN`.  There's a few different types (INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN).

Here's a simple example to get you started:

```
SELECT albums.name AS albums.name, musics.name AS musics_name, musics.releaseDate 
    FROM albums 
    LEFT JOIN musics ON albums.id = musics.albumId 
    ORDER BY musics.releaseDate
```

Or, if you need music and only the album when it matches:

```
SELECT albums.name AS albums.name, musics.name AS musics_name, musics.releaseDate 
    FROM musics 
    LEFT JOIN albums ON musics.albumId = albums.id
    ORDER BY musics.releaseDate
```

Comment: but I have music without album and albumId=null

Comment: @Neron7 - so switch it around so that it's `SELECT ... FROM musics LEFT JOIN albums ...`

Comment: And I play with JOIN but i not give correct result.

Comment: @Neron7 - your question does not specify the result you want.  Please see my edit, and let me know if that helps / gets you what you want.  **If not**, please specify *exactly* what you want.